# Find the number of times an element is repeated in List/Array

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a list/array with each entry of the form [ string -> String[] ]

now I want to find maximum number of times an element is repeated subsequently

Example:

```
hash1 -> [method1, method2 , method3]
hash2 -> [method1, method4]
hash3 -> [method1, method5]
hash4 -> [method1, method2, method5]
hash5 -> [method2]
hash6 -> [method2]
```

Answer is 4 (method1 is subsequently repeated four number of times. we cannot consider the method2 for counting as the maximum number of times it is repeated continuously is 3)

I would really appreciate if I can get the code of this in Java. But other languages will also work.

Comment: Please post your attempts so far and where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a HashMap to keep the current counts, and an int for a longest chain.

```
For each entry in list
    For each string in entry
        If string in HashMap, increment the value
        Else add to HashMap with value 1
    Remove all pairs from HashMap that weren't in the last entry
    Update longest chain length
```

Comment: "Remove all pairs from HashMap that weren't in the last entry" is not correct as Method1 is not there in the last entry, but it has the maximum occurences

Comment: @Robin the question was to find the maximum number, not which entry has the maximum. That is what the longest chain length is for. Even when Method1 is removed from the HashMap, the longest chain length holds 4.